# SSDT project can't reference a cross db trigger - warning SQL71502

Tags: visual-studio-2012, triggers, sql-server-data-tools, database-project, cross-database

I have two SQL 2012 DBs - one has a table with a trigger, the other has a procedure that disables that trigger.

I've created a SSDT solution with 2 database projects, one for each database. For the second database I've added a Database reference pointing to the first database so that I can reference objects - however the line in my procedure:

```
ALTER TABLE [$(DbWithTrigger)].dbo.TblWithTrigger DISABLE TRIGGER MyTrigger
```

brings up the warning:

> SQL71502 Procedure: [dbo].[CrossDbTriggerCall] has an unresolved
>   reference to object [dbo].[MyTrigger].

I'm able to consistently reproduce this behaviour in Visual Studio 2012 SSDT and Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.

Comment: Another possible solution would be to create some sort of "IsTriggerEnabled" table that would store the trigger name and a bit for Enabled. If that row doesn't exist or the Enabled column is True, the trigger body fires. Otherwise, the main part of the trigger would not fire at all. We used that in some former projects and it was a lot easier than altering the tables to disable the trigger and didn't require the higher permissions to alter the tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
DISABLE TRIGGER [$(DbWithTrigger)].[dbo].[MyTrigger] on [$(DbWithTrigger)].[dbo].[TblWithTrigger];
```

in the SP. This should work.

Comment: Yes - that does work. I thought I'd tried that, turns out even the semi-colon is needed - especially one before the "DISABLE"